# Sharing Apple RDP config between local users

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, apple-remote-desktop

I have a Mac Mini setup with Apple Server and Apple Remote Desktop to push profiles and remotely manage other Mac devices on the local network.

I want to give another department access to the Mac Mini Server, so I have created a separate administrative local user account. However, when I open Apple RD on that account, it's empty - no devices or containers.

Is there a way to share the Apple RD config between local users?

[image: Main Admin User Account, Apple RD fully configured]

 *Main Server user account, Apple RDP fully configured*

[image: Other department's Admin User Account, Apple RD with no configuration]

 *Other department's user account, Apple RD with no configuration*

Comment: What version of Apple Remote Desktop and macOS are on your “jump server”?

Comment: Are you referring to Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) or "(Microsoft) Remote Desktop Protocol" or RDP. There is no product by Apple called "Apple RDP." Your screen shots seem to indicate ARD.

Comment: Apple Remote Desktop as tagged - sorry I frequently switch between both. I'm running ARD 3.9.4 and MacOS Big Sur 11.5.2